# UWP C# - Testing two applictions at the same time

Tags: c#, .net-core, uwp

So I was following this Guide - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets

In the guide, they have a Client / Server relationship in a single app. What I want to do is split it into two separate projects and have them talk to each other.

My issue is I have two instances of visual studio running and when I have either the client or server project running and start the other it stops the first project that was running.

I changed the project name and every instance I can find of "Sockets" to "Sockets_Client" or "Sockets_Server"

Comment: make sure your client is not "listening" on your ports

Comment: Just a tip: you can use one instance of visual studio.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2019 fixing your issue will require further information on ports, mutexes etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My issue is I have two instances of visual studio running and when I have either the client or server project running and start the other it stops the first project that was running.

The problem is the solution has same package family name, so it could not install to the system at same time, if you want to make them run at same time please edit one of package family name.

**double click package manifest -> package tab -> edit package family name.**